# How can I display a title of nested foreign key for the productAttribute of features in Django Serializer and React

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

The problem with my code is that it repeats the attribute_title of the productAttribute  for each object whose foreign key is in the productAttribute model in a loop. I want the attribute_title():"حافظه" field to be repeated only once result in react redux to be same :
I want the attribute_title():"حافظه" field to be repeated only once

```
PivotSerialize:
attribute_id(pin):1
product_id(pin):1
attribute_name(pin):"ظرفیت حافظه"
val(pin):"256"
attribute_title(pin):"حافظه" 
attr_title_id(pin):"1"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPf08.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfjJg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P14Wd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICLo8.png)
```

my model is:

```
class AttributeTitle(models.Model):
    attribute_title_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Attribute(models.Model):
    attribute_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    attr_title = models.ForeignKey(AttributeTitle,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='attribute_model_related_name')
    attr_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    p_a_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_attribute')
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

my Serializer api is:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    brands = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    photos = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    color = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    productAttribute = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_category(self, obj):
        category = obj.category
        serializers = CategorySerializer(category, many=False).data
        return serializers

    def get_brands(self, obj):
        brands = obj.brand
        serializers = BrandsSerializer(brands, many=False).data
        return serializers

    def get_photos(self, obj):
        photos = obj.product_images
        serializers = ProductPhotosSerializer(photos, many=True).data
        return serializers

    def get_color(self, obj):
        color = obj.product_color  # ProductColor.objects.filter(product_id=obj._id)
        serializers = ProductColorSerializer(color, many=True).data
        return serializers

    def get_productAttribute(self, obj):
        attribute = obj.product_attribute  # related_name='product_attribute' in ProductAttribute model
        serializers = PivotSerializer(attribute, many=True).data
        return serializers


class PivotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attribute_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    attribute_title = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    val = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    attr_title_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductAttribute
        fields = ['attribute_id', 'product_id', 'attribute_name', 'val', 'attribute_title', 'attr_title_id']

    def get_attr_title_id(self, obj):
        attr = obj.attribute.attr_title.pk
        return str(attr)

    def get_attribute_name(self, obj):
        attr = obj.attribute
        return str(attr)

    def get_attribute_title(self, obj):
        res = obj.attribute.attr_title
        return str(res)

    def get_val(self, obj):
        res = obj.value
        return str(res)
```

The problem with my code is that it repeats the name of the property title for each object whose foreign key is in the product property model in a loop.
I want the attribute_title():"Memory" field to be repeated only once

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI8tT.png)